# Postgres latest column value from each row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql table which is being updated hourly through API. Sample is:

| id | time | firstname | lastname | salary | location | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-08 07:47:58 | John |  | 10000 |  |  |
| 1 | 2023-03-08 07:50:58 |  | Lenny |  | Phoenix | USA |
| 1 | 2023-03-08 07:55:58 |  |  | 5000 |  |  |

What i am looking in target is only 1 row that should contain all latest updated value, so the sample will look somewhat like this:

| id | time | firstname | lastname | salary | location | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-08 07:55:58 | John | Lenny | 5000 | Phoenix | USA |

Is there any way this can be achieved through Postgres query?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Select MAX of each column which should be shown in your result.

Comment: MAX will give MAX value, not latest. Switch salary values in the sample data, so the latest value isn't also the largest value.

Comment: After OP edited their question, in my opinion, it doesn't make sense at all. What to do if some of the values that are currently NULL in the sample data are not null? The question requires improvement to clarify the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small example using array_agg, an order by and a filter:

```
SELECT  id
    ,   MAX(time) as time
    ,   (array_agg(firstname ORDER BY time DESC) FILTER(WHERE firstname IS NOT NULL))[1]    firstname
    ,   (array_agg(salary ORDER BY time DESC) FILTER(WHERE salary IS NOT NULL))[1] salary
FROM        t1
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array_agg can do the trick :

`array_agg` with `order` and `filter` to group data into an array (only not empty data).

In where `filter`, if you have `null` values then use `where column is not null` instead.

`to_json` to transform the array into json then using `->-1` we get the latest element

```
select id, max(time),
  to_json(array_agg(firstname order by time) filter (where firstname <> '' ))->-1 AS firstname,
  to_json(array_agg(lastname order by time) filter (where lastname <> '' ))->-1 AS firstname,
  to_json(array_agg(salary order by time) filter (where salary <> '' ))->-1 AS salary,
  to_json(array_agg(location order by time) filter (where location <> '' ))->-1 AS location,
  to_json(array_agg(country order by time) filter (where country <> '' ))->-1 AS country
from mytable
group by id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1HV_4oO8)

Comment: You have to order descending to get the latest value for a column. And the filtering should be done on NOT NULL because a salary is most likely a number and not a string nor empty string.

Comment: In my case the order by time should by asc, since I extract the latest element, and  regarding the NULL values I can't tell if the empty columns are null or empty

Comment: No, because of the ascending nature of your ordering, you get the first element in time and not the last one. Add an additional record with a different name and a date somewhere in the future and you will still get the old name, not the new one.

Comment: I always get the latest record, because I order by ASC and get the latest one, which will be for sure the latest,  have a look here : https://dbfiddle.uk/vjzbU2EX